# Get chatter feeds what a user follows

Tags: feeditem

I am able to get all of chatter feeds by querying 'FeedItem' object.

For example: SELECT Id, Title, Body FROM FeedItem

But, I am getting trouble to get feeds what a specific follow.

Is it possible to use Apex to get the feeds which a user follows?

Answer (score 2):

You can either find the records a user is following through [EntitySubscription](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm), or leverage the [NewsFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_newsfeed.htm) which will give you the same Feed Items as what you can find on the home tab.

Comment: The "What I follow" is bigger than " EntitySubscription", and it is not the answer. As one doesn't have any " EntitySubscription", one can still have feeds in the "What I follow".

NewsFeed is probably the answer, but it is not supported any more.

Comment: Not sure I got your point. EntitySubscription will get you all the records and users you are following, so you can then get the Feed Items related to these records even if it could be painful. NewsFeed should be easier, and is still supported by the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resource_feeds_news.htm).

Comment: Thank you. yes, it is supported by the REST API. I just found a way to get the expected result of "What I follow". But it does not work with SOQL, it is so painful to query the specific post record (feeditem) and its attributes.

Comment: In Apex, you can use the `ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds` class. Here's an example of getting your news feed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_get_feed_elements.htm